# How to remove the brush is read only in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, readonly, brush, unity3d-terrain

I’m pretty new at Unity, I’ve been trying to add a terrain and add texture but it says “the brush is read only” and I can’t do it. Does anyone know how to deactivate that?

Comment: Well you can't .. if a property is readonly in a precompiled DLL there is no way for you to change that fact .. look for a method that allows you to change that .. otherwise there is no way

Comment: But why do I get this? No one else gets it. Should I try to reinstall unity?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It’s not a code, sadly I can t post a picture, but if you google “the brush is read only” and go to images the first one is what appears to me when I try to edit a terrain.

Answer (score 1):

Is it set to raise or lower terrain? Or is the opacity too low? this happened to me as well which is why i saw this post. There is no problem with regards to the "The brush is read only" i was using the brush but none came out. Then i noticed something, thanks to the lighting the ground seems to have some small bumps. Then I set the brush opacity higher and notice a change. hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

For me I disabled the terrain collider, and by re-enabling it I was able to edit the terrain. It still gave me the read-only error message but I could now edit the terrain.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a terrain texture by click "Edit Terrain Layers" and select "create a layer" option.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your terrain object then under the inspector go to stroke and increase brush size and brush strength that should work, if it doesn't then try changing your layouts to any screen layout the put it back to defaults that should also work I hope this helps you or anyone out there though

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it might be not a "the brush is read only" problem, but a Terrain material thing. Ensure your material in Terrain Settings tab is a Terrain type material, so it would support texture painting.